# get column count if column-count is set to auto

Tags: jquery, css

How can I get the column-count if I set the column-count to auto?
Since my content will be dynamic and I cannot set the column-count to any number. I could generate columns using column-width and setting the height to 300px.

```
.column{
  -webkit-column-width: 130px;
  -moz-column-width: 130px;
  column-width: 130px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: We need more info than this. What jQuery plugin are you using, for instance?

Comment: I am not using any jquery plugin

Comment: Can you just do some math and get the computed column-width and divide it into the column container width?